# Find students who enrolled in a course for which there exists a prerequisite that the student has not passed

Tags: sql

Sometimes I get a syntax error and sometimes I just simply get wrong results.
So I have a table called Enrollment and a table called Prerequisite, they look like:

```
Enrollment(StudentNo, CourseNo, Term, Section, Mark)
    StudentNo and CourseNo are primary keys
Prerequistie(CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo)
     CourseNo and PrereqCourseNo are primary keys
```

So now I want to find students who enrolled in a course which s/he did not have 
the prerequisite, i.e. the course has a prerequisite in the prerequisite table and the student didn't have the prerequisite. A student  did not have a prerequisite for an 
advanced course if there is a prerequisite in which s/he did not enroll, or 
s/he failed a prerequisite. A student failed a course if the course mark s/he 
obtained is less than 50.

So here's what i've got:

```
SELECT distinct Enrollment.StudentNo, enrollment.CourseNo, prereqNeeded.prereq 
from Enrollment, (SELECT ENROLLMENT.CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo, StudentNo
            from enrollment, prerequisite 
                where ENROLLMENT.CourseNo = PREREQUISITE.CourseNo AND 
                NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT StudentNo, MARK 
                FROM ENROLLMENT 
                WHERE enrollment.CourseNo = PrereqCourseNo 
                AND MARK >= 50)) prereqNeeded 
WHERE Enrollment.StudentNo = prereqNeeded.StudentNo 
and prereqNeeded.CourseNo = ENROLLMENT.CourseNo
```

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're getting, or the results that are wrong and then explain what you expect to get?

Comment: What SQL Server are you using?

Comment: If a student can re-take a course, then studentno, courseno are not adequate as primary keys in your first table.

Comment: Would it be too hard to supply a proper title for questions?

Answer (score 2):

First, you probably mean that

`(StudentNo, CourseNo)` is the `Primary Key` of `Enrollment` and that

`(CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo)` is the `Primary Key` of `Prerequistie`

A table has one Primary Key and not many. In this case, the primary keys are not single fields but combinations of two fields.

---

Second, is it `Prerequistie` or **`Prerequisite`** ?

---

Regarding your query, I think this is what you need (updated, first version was wrong):

The query can be reworded like *"Find all student who enrolled in a course for which there **exists a** prerequisite that the student has **not** passed"*

```
SELECT e.StudentNo, e.CourseNo
FROM Enrollment e
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM Prerequisite p
    WHERE p.CourseNo = e.CourseNo
      AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM Enrollment ep
              WHERE ep.CourseNo = p.PrereqCourseNo
                AND ep.StudentNo = e.StudentNo
                AND ep.Mark >= 50
            )
  )
```

Comment: Using EXISTS makes it indeed more concise and easy on the eye. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CurrentPrereqs.StudentNo, CurrentPrereqs.CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo, Mark
FROM
  (SELECT StudentNo, Current.CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo
     FROM
       (SELECT * from Enrollment where Mark IS NULL) AS Current
     LEFT JOIN Prerequisite p ON Current.CourseNo=p.CourseNo
  ) AS CurrentPrereqs
LEFT JOIN Enrollment PreviousMarks
ON (CurrentPrereqs.StudentNo=PreviousMarks.StudentNo AND
    CurrentPrereqs.PrereqCourseNo=PreviousMarks.CourseNo)
WHERE PreviousMarks.Mark IS NULL OR PreviousMarks.Mark <50;
```

Some test data: Course 101 is a prerequisite for courses 202 and 2202; Course 202 is a prerequisite for course 303, course 1101 is a prerequisite for course 2202:

```
select * from Prerequisite;
+----------+----------------+
| CourseNo | PrereqCourseNo |
+----------+----------------+
|      202 |            101 |
|      303 |            202 |
|     2202 |            101 |
|     2202 |           1101 |
+----------+----------------+
```

Two students, one which is trying to take 2202 without taking 1101 (but having passed 101); another trying to take 202 after failing 101:

```
select * from Enrollment order by StudentNo;
+-----------+----------+------+---------+------+
| StudentNo | CourseNo | Term | Section | Mark |
+-----------+----------+------+---------+------+
|         1 |      101 | F01  |       1 |   92 |
|         1 |      202 | S01  |       1 |   88 |
|         1 |      303 | F02  |       1 | NULL |
|         1 |     2202 | F02  |       1 | NULL |
|         2 |      101 | F01  |       2 |   48 |
|         2 |      202 | F02  |       2 | NULL |
+-----------+----------+------+---------+------+
```

The current classes the students are enrolled in have a NULL Mark (for now).

The result of the query is:

```
+-----------+----------+----------------+------+
| StudentNo | CourseNo | PrereqCourseNo | Mark |
+-----------+----------+----------------+------+
|         1 |     2202 |           1101 | NULL |
|         2 |      202 |            101 |   48 |
+-----------+----------+----------------+------+
```

Comment: In this answer if the prerequisite course was not taken it'll appear as a row with a NULL Mark.

Comment: With the (perhaps valid) assumption that recent Enrollments have `NULL` as Mark, it's a nice solution.

Comment: Indeed.  looking at it a second time I noticed how unreadable it is.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to jump out at me is

```
 SELECT distinct Enrollment.StudentNo, enrollment.CourseNo, prereqNeeded.prereq 
from Enrollment, (SELECT ENROLLMENT.CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo, StudentNo
            from enrollment, prerequisite 
                where ENROLLMENT.CourseNo = PREREQUISITE.CourseNo AND 
                NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT StudentNo, MARK 
                FROM ENROLLMENT 
                WHERE enrollment.CourseNo = PrereqCourseNo 
                AND MARK >= 50)) prereqNeeded 
WHERE Enrollment.StudentNo = prereqNeeded.StudentNo 
and prereqNeeded.CourseNo = ENROLLMENT.CourseNo
```

I think you need to keep the case of the table names.

```
 SELECT distinct Enrollment.StudentNo, Enrollment.CourseNo, prereqNeeded.prereq 
from Enrollment, (SELECT Enrollment.CourseNo, PrereqCourseNo, StudentNo
            from Enrollment, Prerequisite 
                where Enrollment.CourseNo = Prerequisite.CourseNo AND 
                NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT StudentNo, MARK 
                FROM Enrollment 
                WHERE Enrollment.CourseNo = PrereqCourseNo 
                AND MARK >= 50)) prereqNeeded 
WHERE Enrollment.StudentNo = prereqNeeded.StudentNo 
and prereqNeeded.CourseNo = Enrollment.CourseNo
```

Could be wrong but on the DB I use it complains about this.